# How can I keep quads flat when fitting a mesh to a curve?

Tags: bezier-curves, normals

I'm making a race track using a bezier curve and a simple mesh with an array and curve modifier to fit the curves. This is for a racing game in Unity.

When moving the model from Blender to Unity, I noticed the faces of the track get triangulated, and that the tris *also* fit the curve. The result of this is that the quads are no longer flat where the track tilts left or right; instead there are  now 2 tris at slightly different angles causing a very bumpy and uncomfortable ride for the car that's driving on them.

In the top screenshot is what the quads look like in Blender. As you can see, they are perfectly flat and the shading changes with each quad. The bottom screenshot is after applying all modifiers and then triangulating the faces. Here you can see that the areas that were quads are no longer flat. The way the shading changes from one tri to the next shows the "bumpiness" I'm talking about.

Is there a way to apply these curves to my mesh without messing up the quads? I understand triangulation is necessary but I don't understand why each quad ends up with 2 tris that each have different normals than the original quad.

[image]

Comment: I'm not expert of Unity, but I think that you should simply add some more subdivisions to the base mesh, so that the bumpiness will be more subtle and even.

Comment: ...also, it doesn't look as if the rectangular array elements are merged along the curve.. adjacent vertices will have slightly different normals... possibly check 'merge' in the array modifier, increase the merge distance, slightly?

Comment: @joshsanfelici Subdivisions will only make it bumpier. The problem isn't the lack of smoothness overall, it's the lack of smoothness within each quad; the resulting tris cause the curve to be a series of very slight inclines and declines instead of each face being a greater angle than the last.

Comment: @RobinBetts They are merged, and the distance was increased. It may look like they aren't because I'm using flat shading. Thanks but this is a different issue!